# Build a Third Party API Using Django

Tags: django, api

I am interested in building a third party software to provide service through API. But the problem is I don't have any in depth knowledge related to this (i.e how am I suppose to count the api calls, where I will store the data from both side like this) Can someone suggest me some resources that will help me to go through this. Thank you!

Comment: You can use inbuilt database system to keep count for api calls. It also has inbuilt auth system so you can use that to count api calls per user if you want.  [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/) will guide you to get started with databse in django.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you write your own middleware. A stated on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/

> Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input or output.

For each request made to your API you can keep track of it in the database. Just create a model for it and add a new entry on every request via the middleware

Comment: Can you please suggest me some resources where I can learn how to build a third party web app. This will be great. Thank you

Comment: If you‘d like to build with Django you can start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/ for basic programming look at pluralsight, coursera, youtube tutorials, lydia etc